# When image inside of a div element hovered get another div element?

Tags: html, css, image

So in CSS this is possible:

```
#Something1:hover .Something22 {...}
```

But when I put it like this:

```
#Something1 img:hover .Something22 {...}
```

It doesn't work. Is this possible for just images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#Something1 img:hover .Something22 {...}
```

would mean your element with class `Something22` is inside the `img` element. This wouldn't be valid.

If your element with class `Something22` is just after the image, maybe you want

```
#Something1 img:hover + .Something22 {...}
```

Or if your image is of class `Something22`, then you need this :

```
#Something1 img.Something22:hover {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

The latter doesnt work because an `img` element can never have descendants. That is just invalid HTML.

To quote the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements) on HTML syntax (emphasis mine):

> A void element is an element whose content model never allows it to
>   have contents under any circumstances. Void elements can have
>   attributes.
>
> The following is a complete list of the void elements in HTML:
>
> area, base, br, col, command, embed, hr, **img**, input, keygen, link, meta, param, source, track, wbr

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because your first selector:

```
#Something1:hover .Something22 {...}
```

selects an item with the class `Something22` that is inside an element with the ID `Something1` while it is being hovered over.

Your second class selects an item with the class `Something22` that is inside an image. An image cannot contain another element and as such your second selector does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use jQuery

```
$('#Something1 img').hover(
    function(){
        // do you stuff with Something22 here
    },
    function(){}
);
```